# GPO User Registry preference - value gets put in an additional Run key

Tags: registry, gpo

I have a simple value I want to add into HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run via User GPO using registry preferences.

I have a GPO which has no other settings apart from this registry preference, and it works.

I don't want to just have a GPO which only sets this value, so I copied and pasted the settings into another GPO, which has other settings in Administrative Templates (no other reg prefs). When this GPO applies, it creates an additional Run key under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion, so you can see two Run keys. The exe pointed to in the second Run key does not work (not surprisingly), but works fine if I recreate by hand in the "normal" run key (or obviously let the original GPO apply instead).

I put on GPO logging, as decribed in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2015/04/17/a-treatise-on-group-policy-troubleshootingnow-with-gpsvc-log-analysis/ but there is nothing in the logs created that indicates where the issue lies.

I am not allowed to use any sysinternals tools, so can't use something like regmon to see if that gives any clues.

I compared the XML for the reg prefs (clicking on the reg pref entry, and dragging to a windows folder, which will create the XML) and they both look identical, apart from the UID (obviously) and displayDecimal (working one has 1, the other has 0).

I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

I did an export from the registry and it showed a space after "Run ". This did not show up in the XML, and did not look like it existed in the GPMC GUI.

Unsure if this question/answer is actually worth leaving here, as the root of the answer seems quite obvious, in retrospect - you can have two different reg keys with the same name!